# Swift Check if plist file exist

Tags: swift, plist

How can I check if a `plist` file exists?

I'm trying something like this:

```
if let dictFile = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: "file.plist") {

}
```

But I get this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Is anyway to check if a `plist` file exist before use it?

Comment: That code snippet should be fine, it doesn't force unwrap anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a URLPath, in the way you are doing, there's no folder or reference.
I'm assuming that you're using a plist in the main bundle.

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "plist"), let dataDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath){
           .
           . 
           .
        }
```